# The original Infinity Gauntlet

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

As was [already explained in this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64885/has-marvel-commented-on-the-extra-infinity-gauntlet) two Infinity Gauntlets have appeared in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, one in Odin's Vault and one used by Thanos in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hela states that the gauntlet in Odin's vault is a fake. But since this one is shown in the first *Thor* movie, it predates the one that was **constructed** on Nidavellir by many years.

Since nothing can be a fake copy of something constructed years later, this implies that there is an **Original Infinity Gauntlet**, or at least an original design/mythical ancient weapon either lost through a plothole (or hopefully saved for later...?).

Has anyone heard or read a mention of this in interviews/tweets/comic adaptations of the MCU?

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64885/has-marvel-commented-on-the-extra-infinity-gauntlet/190902#190902) it is stated that (apparently) the Asgardians are aware of such device, and Odin's Gauntlet is a cheap *imitation of something that already exists*, not a mass destruction weapon in development.

So, it had to be invented or at least designed before. This is supported by he fact that this *has* to be a glove. And taking into account that the stones are there since the Big Bang this is not impossible.

Comment: Fake doesn't imply that there has to have been an original. Every year there are dozens of paintings sold that are 'fakes' but that are also original artworks in their own right.

Comment: But... how can something original be a fake...? How can you tell, in the case of the gauntlet that it is a fake if there has never existed another gauntlet before???

Comment: Ultimately the gauntlet is a device. If I made a space laser out of papier-mache and spackle, you'd know it was fake without there ever having been a real space laser to compare it to.

Comment: Yes, but... the concept 'space laser' already exists in science fiction and it was invented by someone, so there is at least an original concept. The fake Gauntlet issue is like having a chinese ipod BEFORE Steve Jobs birth. Someone at least had to have the idea that the stones could be put in a glove instead of a sceptre or a sword.

Comment: What's to say that the "original" gauntlet wasn't Odin's invention.

Comment: And his fake gauntlet was like a dummy or prototype? That could be it. Maybe there is a mention of this somewhere...

Comment: I stand corrected. Odin and the Asgardians ***were*** (apparently) aware of its existence so Odin had a fake one made; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/190902/20774

Comment: @LudovicoN: “How can you tell, in the case of the gauntlet that it is a fake if there has never existed another gauntlet before???” Pop the Infinity Stones into it, and click your fingers. If nothing happens, it was a fake.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite If it's a fake, you probably wouldn't even get as far as putting all of the Infinity Stones into it. The first one would probably be sufficient to destroy it.

Comment: +1 for interesting question.  But you definitely can have a "fake" before there's a "real" through basic false advertising.  ::slaps gauntlet:: "This baby can hold so many Infinity Stones" (when in fact it can hold zero).  Or even just "This is what an Infinity Gauntlet would *look* like."

Comment: There's possibly another "fake" in the vault as well. While everyone assumed that the Eye of Agamotto" was in the vault, we learned later it wasn't. So the thing in the vault back in the first Thor film is either some other artifact, or possibly another lie.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet If this was a non-functional prototype. How can you know that Thanos' one will work? On the other hand... if it's as easy as to pop some stones into it... why on Asgard wouldn't Odin keep an entirely functional weapon of mass destruction in his posession, instead of that cheap toy?

Comment: As others have mentioned, the first gauntlet being fake could simply mean it does not function the way one might claim or believe it does. I could stack some cardboard boxes together and claim I've invented the world's first teleporter; it was "made" before any real teleporters, and is certainly a fake because it will not actually teleport anyone anywhere.

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't mean that I can make something really functional by following your design. As we know by now, [is impossible to make a fully functional lightsaber](https://www.livescience.com/50728-secrets-of-the-jedi-lightsaber-infographic.html) or an exact replica of the enterprise with antimatter engines included. To make a fully functional gauntlet means there was at least a tested prototype and, as I said before, the choice of the designer to make it a glove instead of another type of weapon.

Comment: I am totally with @Valorum re: a fake object does not need to be an ersatz copy of an existing object. See [**vaporware**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporware) offerings such as [the paper ink pen with 16 million digitally-controlled ink colors that does not exist](https://futurism.com/revolutionary-pen-draws-color-probably-isnt-real/).

Comment: [Fake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fake): *something that is intended **to look like and be mistaken for something else***, esp. a copy made in order to deceive:. My question is about a mention of that **something else** in MCU and MCU related sources.

Answer (score 5):

> In Thor: Ragnarok, Hela states that the gauntlet in Odin's vault is a fake. But since this one is shown in the first Thor movie, it predates the one that was constructed on Nidavellir by many years.

This is true. We know that the gauntlet that Thanos uses in *Avengers: Infinity War* was very likely created sometime after the start of *Thor: the Dark World*, given the discussion Odin and Thor had.

> ODIN (TO THOR): "For the first time since the Bifrost was destroyed, the Nine Realms are at peace. They're well reminded of our strength, and you have earned their respect and my gratitude."
>
> <sub><sup>*Thor: The Dark World*</sup></sub>

We also know it was made before the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, where we first saw it in the [post-credits scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzWNBmjyv7Y). According to [Joe Russo in an interview](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/07/avengers-infinity-war-ultron-gauntlet-plot-hole-explained/), the gauntlet scene in *Ultron* may take place on Nidavellir itself, which gives us a pretty concrete argument for this one coming significantly later than the fake.

This actually doesn't tell us a whole lot about the fake itself though. While it's possible that there was an earlier ancient version (one Thanos could have based his own on), it's equally possible that Thanos had multiple prototypes constructed (potentially including the one in Odin's vault) before having the Dwarves create the final superior version, and the one that he ended up using. Beyond that, I've yet to find any official sources addressing this with finality, so it's impossible to be certain for now.

Comment: It's also possible that Odin's gauntlet was a fake but not a copy of Thanos'. Just to add a further idea...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think that'd the idea the original question was already posing: that it was a fake based on an older non-Thanos gauntlet.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not entirely sure what the idea in the OP is. Mu comment was mainly referring to this line in the OP though "Since nothing can be a fake copy of something constructed years later".

Comment: This puts the destruction of Nidavellir under the responsability of Odin and puts Thor as a liar by explaining the dwarf that he dind't defended them because of Ragnarok.

Comment: @LudovicoN Potentially. We see Thanos already pulling out the gauntlet at the end of Age of Ultron in response to those events, so regardless of whether or not it occurred before Thor 1, it was still before Ragnarok (although one could argue Thor may not have known, and Odin had been effectively out of commission since the end of Thor 2). Still, you bring up a good point about Asgard's role in protection, especially in light of a line given in Thor 2. I'm going to make an edit.

Comment: Maybe Thanos isn't the first person to think of harnessing the infinity stones' power with a gauntlet.